# programmatically accessing webcontrols (Via FindControl)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm relatively new to .net and I'm trying to enable/disable text boxes based on the value of a dropdown box. (the user select 5 places and only 5 (well 10, two lots of 5) boxes are displayed).

From reading around the subject here and elsewhere on line I think FindControl is the way to go (locate the controls on the page and make then visible or not as needed), however the below code generates a NullReferenceException on txtBox.Visible = True because, txtBox is "Nothing".

```
        Dim txtBox As TextBox = New TextBox()
        Dim textboxName As String
```

...

```
        For LoopCounter = 1 To 10
            If LoopCounter < ddNumberOfPlaces.SelectedValue + 1 Then
                textboxName = "txtGuestName" + CStr(LoopCounter)
                txtBox = CType(FindControl(textboxName), TextBox)
                txtBox.Visible = True
                txtBox = CType(FindControl("txtGuestOrganisation" + CStr(LoopCounter)), TextBox)
                txtBox.Visible = True
            Else
                txtBox = CType(FindControl("txtGuestName" + CStr(LoopCounter)), TextBox)
                txtBox.Visible = False
                txtBox = CType(FindControl("txtGuestOrganisation" + CStr(LoopCounter)), TextBox)
                txtBox.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
```

So What am I doing wrong? and is this even the best way to implement this?

Thanks in Advance.

P.S. textboxName does (at the point of the exception) contain a valid control id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using master page, then FindControl does not work. FindControl returns only the top level controls. It does not find the control recursively. You can use the following function to find the controls recursively. Instead of calling FindControl, call this function.

```
     Private Function FindControlRecursive(ByVal rootControl As Control, ByVal controlID As String) As Control
        If (rootControl.ID = controlID) Then
            FindControlRecursive = rootControl
        Else
            For Each controlToSearch As Control In rootControl.Controls

                Dim controlToReturn As Control = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID)
                If (controlToReturn IsNot Nothing) Then
                    FindControlRecursive = controlToReturn
                End If

            Next
            FindControlRecursive = Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

---

Thanks. Your function appeared to always return "Nothing" so I amended it slightly.

```
Private Function FindControlRecursive(ByVal rootControl As Control, ByVal controlID As String) As Control

    Dim controlToReturn As Control = Nothing

    If (rootControl.ID = controlID) Then
        controlToReturn = rootControl
    Else
        For Each controlToSearch As Control In rootControl.Controls
            If (controlToReturn Is Nothing) Then
                controlToReturn = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    FindControlRecursive = controlToReturn
End Function
```